# Confused with partial derivatives in thermodynamics

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let the Van der Waal gas $(p + a/V²)(V-b) = RT$. I want to understand once and for all how to evaluate partial derivatives like $(\partial p / \partial T)_{V}$. The answer should be $R/(V-b)$, which is just the partial derivative wrt to T, nothing new, but this is generally not true in another case, so i am trying to understand why does this happens and when we can do that? That is a question that is puzzling me.

Maybe it is instructive to write more carefully.
$p = p(T,V); dp = (\partial p / \partial T)_{V}dT + (\partial p / \partial V)_{T} dV$

So that $dp = (\partial p / \partial T)_{V}dT$, $dp/dT = (\partial p / \partial T)_{V}$

In this last expression, can we "confuse on purpose" dp/dt with partial derivatives? This is the answer?

Comment: The version of Van der Waals you're using doesn't have $n$ in it, so it is the intensive version, and you should be using the variable $v=V/n$ instead of $V$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Downvoter: is there something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider what the partial derivative even *means* in the first place. The partial derivative $(\partial p/\partial v)$ means we want to look at $\Delta p/\Delta v$ along a path (in the space of all states of the system, AKA configuration space) in which $v$ tends to some specified value $v_0$. But *we get different limits along different paths*, so physically this is ambiguous without further information. Some more information is that we're choosing a coordinate system $(p,v,T)$ for our configuration space, our set of states is then graphed as a surface, and we can find $\partial p/\partial v$ along a very conventional path: the one in which $T$ is constant. After all, with these coordinates, we can write $p$ as a function $p(v,T)$ of $v$ and $T$, with an approximate explicit formula under nice circumstances (via van der Waals), and then do the usual Calc I thing.

But when you study more thermodynamics, you will find more physical quantities than just $p,v,T$ that describe a system's state, so in other words our configuration space can have *different* coordinate systems. Instead of $(p,v,T)$ to describe a physical state you could use $(p,v,\ast)$ for some other physical quantity $\ast$, in which case the partial derivatives $(\partial p/\partial v)_T$ and $(\partial p/\partial T)_\ast$ will be different. Some other quantities I encountered in my thermo class were internal energy $U$, enthalpy $H$, entropy $S$, Helmholtz free energy $F$ and Gibbs free energy $G$ (in that order, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

From the state equation if Van der Wall,

we get

$$p=\frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2}$$

to get $\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\Bigr)_V$, you differentiate the expression above according to $ T $ and assuming $ V $ is constant.

it gives
$$\frac{R}{V-b}$$
which should be denoted
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\Bigr)_{V}$$
and

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\Bigr)_T=-\frac{RT}{(V-b)^2}+\frac{2a}{V^3}$$

Comment: But so, here, why the index V  is necessary? I mean, the partial derivative wrt T automatically assume V constant. Right? Why is this case we could drop the V index, and in another case we can't?

It is because V and T are independent variable?

Comment: The index $ _V $ means that $ V $ is considered as a constant.

Comment: @hamam_Adballah Yes, i see that. But my question is more or less this: The partial derivative ALREADY assume all the other quantities as constant in the derivatives, it doesn't? So why in some cases, as the above $(\partial p/ \partial t) = (\partial p/ \partial t)_{V}$?

Comment: When we differentiate according to a variable, we keep the others constant.

Comment: @hamam_Adballah but so the index is useless, because the partial derivative already implies that :/

Comment: I don't think this is particularly helpful to a student of thermodynamics. As I discuss in my answer, in thermodynamics there are many physical quantities under investigation, and so we switch between many coordinate systems, so it can be ambiguous which variable you are holding constant, really.

Comment: @runway44 So, give us better.

Comment: I posted my answer *before* your challenge - perhaps you just didn't refresh the page to see it. But I shouldn't have to write an answer for permission to criticize yours. In any case, I stand by my criticism: you only provide some calculations, which OP did not ask for; you not only did not answer OP's question, but didn't even attempt to answer it, which seems like a conscious dismissal of it, despite it being a fundamental point of confusion for thermo students. You also reproduced OP's error in using $V$ instead of $v$, and write $``dp/dT"$ which is a big no-no in thermo!

Comment: For instance, writing an expression like $dQ/dT$ would lead someone unable to distinguish between isobaric heat capacity $C_P=(\partial Q/\partial T)_P$ and isochoric heat capacity $C_V=(\partial Q/\partial T)_V$. Because this answer is both unhelpful and misleading, and failed to be fixed or deleted after this was pointed out, I downvoted it. If you are responsible for the downvote on my answer and you have a reason for it other than spite, I welcome you to offer a criticism of your own so mine may be improved or fixed (and if you didn't downvote my answer, then nevermind).